# looping through an array to check checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Am I on the right tract with this? I'm switching my way of doing this since this works best.

What I am doing is taking an series of numbers

```
var n = "1,3,8,12,2,19";
```

I have the following for checking the checkbox:

```
$('#chk1').attr('checked', true)
```

Is there a way to replace the 1 in chk1 with the number in n? I want to loop through the array of numbers and check all the boxes with that number.

Comment: "I want to loop through the array of numbers " make it an array then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$.each (n.split(','), function (index, value) {
   $('#chk' + value).attr('checked', true);
});
```

It is easier if you have `n` like below,

```
var n = [1, 3, 8, 12, 2, 9];//array
$.each (n, function (index, value) {
   $('#chk' + value).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var n = "1,3,8,12,2,19", // not an Array but a String
    arr = n.split(',');  // now it turns to Array like [1, 3, 8, 12, 2, 9]

// loop over array
for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
   $('#chk' + arr[i]).attr('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = n.split(',');

$(nums).each(function(){
    $('#chk' + this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var nums = [1,3,8,12,2,19];

$(nums).each(function() {
    $('#chk' + this).prop('checked', true);
});